# Divisibility by $p^8$ (variation on Wolstenholme's theorem)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, algebraic-number-theory

Prove that for primes $p≥5$: $\binom{p^3}{p^2}-\binom{p^2}{p} ⋮ p^8$. Three vertical dots stand for "is divisible by".

**Thoughts**:

Let $p≥5$ be a prime. Then for $n≥2$, the $p$-valuation of $\binom{p^n}{p^{n-1}}-\binom{p^{n-1}}{p^{n-2}}$ is $3n−1$. Here the $p$-valuation of an integer $m$ is $\nu_{p}(m)=\max \{k: p^{k} \mid m\}$. In fact, I can't even see a simple proof for $n=2$, as it seems that there are at least $2$ powers of $p$ that are not "obvious".

I suspect that a proof is somehow obtainable using a refinement of the following well known observation that is true in any commutative ring: If $x \equiv y \operatorname{mod} p^{k}$, then $x^{p} \equiv y^{p} \operatorname{mod} p^{k+1}$. The idea is to use it somehow, starting with $(1+x)^{p} \equiv 1+x^{p} \operatorname{mod} p$. But I don’t see how to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you exacly want? a proof for $n=2$, a proof for the general fact? Is the general fact true or just a conjecture? If it is true, do you have a source for it?

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez What I want is written in the first sentence. This is not a conjecture, but my "research project" and as far as I know this is true. It just so happens that it's too difficult for me to figure this out on my own.

Comment: For notation, why not just use the far-more-standard vertical bar for "divides", as in "$p|a^p-a$" and such?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Actually the standard is `\mid` as in "$p \mid a^p-a$".

Comment: @user21820HATESSMOKING-HATS, ah, indeed, thanks. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett I don't like it.

Comment: @Cornifer, well, tastes vary. If effective communication is the top priority, speaking the language of your audience is surely also a high priority. Not to forget the human factor: if you create new notations where others already exist, you tend to reduce your own credibility, and people will take you less seriously, etc. There are two different things: notation, and content. I myself do also have strong opinions about notation, but, still, content surely is more important, and we don't want communication of that to be impeded by essentially irrelevant things...? Depends on one's priorities...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll prove the general version. Let $S$ be the set of integers at most $p^{n-1}$ that are relatively prime to $p$. We compute
$$\binom{p^n}{p^{n-1}}=\prod_{i=1}^{p^{n-1}}\frac{p^n-i}{i}=\prod_{i\in S}\frac{p^n-i}{i}\prod_{i=1}^{p^{n-2}}\frac{p^{n-1}-i}{i}=\binom{p^{n-1}}{p^{n-2}}\prod_{i\in S}\left(1-\frac{p^n}i\right),$$
where we have used that $|S|=p^{n-2}(p-1)$ is even. Since
$$\nu_p\left(\binom{p^{n-1}}{p^{n-2}}\right)=1,$$
we need to show that
$$\prod_{i\in S}\left(1-\frac{p^n}i\right)\equiv 1\pmod{p^{3n-2}}.$$
We expand
$$\prod_{i\in S}\left(1-\frac{p^n}i\right)=1-p^n\sum_{i\in S}\frac1i+p^{2n}\sum_{\{i_1,i_2\}\subset S}\frac1{i_1i_2}\pmod{p^{3n}}\tag{1}.$$
Let
$$s_1=\sum_{i\in S}\frac1i\text{ and }s_2=\sum_{i\in S}\frac1{i^2}.$$
We first claim that $s_1\equiv s_2\equiv 0\pmod{p^{n-1}}$. Indeed, since $S$ is closed under inversion (modulo $p^{n-1}$),
$$s_1\equiv \sum_{i\in S}i\pmod{p^{n-1}}\text{ and }s_2\equiv \sum_{i\in S}i^2\pmod{p^{n-1}}.$$
We can explicitly calculate, if $q=p^{n-1}$,
$$s_1=\frac{q(q+1)}2-p\frac{q/p(q/p+1)}2\equiv 0\pmod q$$
and
$$s_2=\frac{q(q+1)(2q+1)}{6}-p^2\frac{(q/p)(q/p+1)(2q/p+1)}{6}\equiv 0\pmod q,$$
using that $p\not\in\{2,3\}$. Now, we have by (1) that
$$\prod_{i\in S}\left(1-\frac{p^n}i\right)\equiv 1-p^ns_1+\frac{p^{2n}(s_1^2-s_2)}{2}\equiv 1-p^ns_1\pmod{p^{3n-1}}.$$
So, we need only to show that
$$s_1\equiv 0\pmod{p^{2n-2}}.$$
Now,
$$2s_1=\sum_{i\in S}\frac1i+\sum_{i\in S}\frac1{p^{n-1}-i}=p^{n-1}\sum_{i\in S}\frac1{i(p^{n-1}-i)}\equiv -p^{n-1}s_2\pmod{p^{2n-2}}.$$
Since $s_2\equiv 0\pmod{p^{n-1}}$, this is $0$, so $s_1\equiv 0\pmod{p^{2n-2}}$, as desired.